# Error return as the JS file is looking for top function in all HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm going to keep this simple:

- 1 JS File
- 3 HTML Files (named: Cars, Trees, House)
- 1 CSS files.

All the functions are thrown into the JS file. But the problem is if I click on the submit 'button' in Cars the JS File will start with the (tree's) function at the top and will look for the addEventListener, if it can't find it it will come back with error 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' - problem is at:

```
tree_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
```

I just want the Js file to execute the function that the HTML file is asking it to.
So in this case its the 'Car' functions that follow the tree functions.

If I separate everything and put it into individual projects or throw the JS in with the referenced HTML file it all works fine, problem occurs only when I put all functions in one JS file.

**HTML Cars**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Car Form</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="cars-body">
   <div class="car_container">
     <div class="car_heading_form">
       <h2> Car Form</h2>
     </div>
     <form id="car_form" class="car_form">
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carName">Car Name</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="hank" id="carName" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Error message</small>
       </div>
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carColor">Car Color</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Gold" id="carColor" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Error message</small>
       </div>
       <button>Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

**JS**

```
// Tree Form
const tree_form = document.getElementById('tree_form');
const treeName = document.getElementById('treeName');
const treeHeight = document.getElementById('treeHeight');

tree_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    tree_Inputs();
});

function tree_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const treerNameValue = treeName.value.trim();
    const treeHeightValue = treeHeight.value.trim();

    if (treeNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForTree(treeName, 'Please enter a name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForTree(treeName);
    }

    if (treeHeightValue === '') {
        setErrorForTree(treeHeight, 'Please enter a number.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForTree(treeHeight);
    }
}

function setErrorForTree(input, message) {
    const formControlTree = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlTree.querySelector('small');
    formControlTree.className = 'tree-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForTree(input) {
    const formControlTree = input.parentElement;
    formControlCar.className = 'tree-form-control success';
}



// Car Form
const car_form = document.getElementById('car_form');
const carName = document.getElementById('carName');
const carColor = document.getElementById('carColor');

car_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    car_Inputs();
});

function car_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const carNameValue = carName.value.trim();
    const carColorValue = carColor.value.trim();

    if (carNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carName, 'Please enter a name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carName);
    }

    if (carColorValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carColor, 'Please a color.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carColor);
    }
}

function setErrorForCar(input, message) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlCar.querySelector('small');
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForCar(input) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control success';
}
```

**CSS**

```
  /***** CONTACT US PAGE CSS *****/

  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .car-body, tree-body {
      min-height: 1300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0px;
  }

  .car_container, .tree_container {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      max-width: 100%;
  }

  .car_heading_form,   .tree_heading_form {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      padding: 20px 40px;
  }

.car_heading_form h2  {
   margin: 0px;
      color: Blue;
} 

.tree_heading_form h2 {
      margin: 0px;
      color: green;
  }

  .car_form, .tree_form {
      padding: 30px 40px;
  }

  .car-form-control, .tree-form-control  {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
  }

  .car-form-control label, .tree-form-control label {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: 530;
      font-size: 17px;
  }

  .car-form-control input, .tree-form-control input {
      border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .car-form-control input:focus, .tree-form-control input:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-color: #777;
  }

  .car-form-control.success input, .tree-form-control.success input {
      border-color: green;
  }

  .car-form-control.error input,   .tree-form-control.error input {
      border-color: red;
  }


  .car-form-control i,   .tree-form-control i {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: 10px;
  }

  .car-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle,   .tree-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
      color: green;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle,   .tree-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
      color: red;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car-form-control small, .tree-form-control small {
      color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
  }

  .car-form-control.error small, .tree-form-control.error small {
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car_form button {
      background-color: rgb(31, 136, 229);
      border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .car_form button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(25, 60, 173);
  }
```

Comment: In the html is no `id="tree_form"` to refer to with `document.getElementById('tree_form');` . Use the id names of your html inputs in your js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

1. I would prefer to create a namespace in JS if there is lots of things I need to add in just a single JS.

   var yourNamespace = {

   ```
    Car: function() {
    },

    Tree: function() {
    },
    House: function() { 
    }
   ```

   };

and in last call it `yourNamespace.Car()` when you click on submit.

This is a working scenario:

```js
    var yourNamespace = {};
yourNamespace = {

    Tree: function() {
const tree_form = document.getElementById('tree_form');
const treeName = document.getElementById('treeName');
const treeHeight = document.getElementById('treeHeight');

tree_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    tree_Inputs();
});

function tree_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const treerNameValue = treeName.value.trim();
    const treeHeightValue = treeHeight.value.trim();

    if (treeNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForTree(treeName, 'Please enter a name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForTree(treeName);
    }

    if (treeHeightValue === '') {
        setErrorForTree(treeHeight, 'Please enter a number.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForTree(treeHeight);
    }
}

function setErrorForTree(input, message) {
    const formControlTree = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlTree.querySelector('small');
    formControlTree.className = 'tree-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForTree(input) {
    const formControlTree = input.parentElement;
    formControlCar.className = 'tree-form-control success';
}

    },

    Car: function() {
const car_form = document.getElementById('car_form');
const carName = document.getElementById('carName');
const carColor = document.getElementById('carColor');

car_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    car_Inputs();
});

function car_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const carNameValue = carName.value.trim();
    const carColorValue = carColor.value.trim();

    if (carNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carName, 'Please enter a name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carName);
    }

    if (carColorValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carColor, 'Please a color.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carColor);
    }
}

function setErrorForCar(input, message) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlCar.querySelector('small');
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForCar(input) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control success';
}
    },
    House: function() { 
    }

};
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .car-body, tree-body {
      min-height: 1300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0px;
  }

  .car_container, .tree_container {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      max-width: 100%;
  }

  .car_heading_form,   .tree_heading_form {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      padding: 20px 40px;
  }

.car_heading_form h2  {
   margin: 0px;
      color: Blue;
} 

.tree_heading_form h2 {
      margin: 0px;
      color: green;
  }

  .car_form, .tree_form {
      padding: 30px 40px;
  }

  .car-form-control, .tree-form-control  {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
  }

  .car-form-control label, .tree-form-control label {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: 530;
      font-size: 17px;
  }

  .car-form-control input, .tree-form-control input {
      border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .car-form-control input:focus, .tree-form-control input:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-color: #777;
  }

  .car-form-control.success input, .tree-form-control.success input {
      border-color: green;
  }

  .car-form-control.error input,   .tree-form-control.error input {
      border-color: red;
  }


  .car-form-control i,   .tree-form-control i {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: 10px;
  }

  .car-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle,   .tree-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
      color: green;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle,   .tree-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
      color: red;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car-form-control small, .tree-form-control small {
      color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
  }

  .car-form-control.error small, .tree-form-control.error small {
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .car_form button {
      background-color: rgb(31, 136, 229);
      border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .car_form button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(25, 60, 173);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="cars-body">
   <div class="car_container">
     <div class="car_heading_form">
       <h2> Car Form</h2>
     </div>
     <form id="car_form" class="car_form">
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carName">Car Name</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="hank" id="carName" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Error message</small>
       </div>
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carColor">Car Color</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Gold" id="carColor" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Error message</small>
       </div>
       <button onClick="yourNamespace.Car()">Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
   </div>
```

2. check on id which form is currently visible (not preferable in your situation, better to use features that JS provide)

Comment: I think this will be the best option as I have other things that need to be called besides forms, therefore I could assign all of them to the namespace

Comment: I'm confused about one thing. Your first instruction 'var youNamespace{ car function() etc...' Does that go at the top of the JS file?
Then following this would you write ' var yourNamespace = {};
yourNamespace = {

Comment: followed by 
car: function() {
Tree: function() {
const tree_form = document.getElementById('tree_form');
const treeName = document.getElementById('treeName');
const treeHeight = document.getElementById('treeHeight');

tree_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    tree_Inputs();
});

Comment: I didn't get your question. but main thing var yourNamespace = {}; in 1st line. Its a declaration then all function in yourNamespace will be as it is. so if you replace your js with this it will work. if you properly format your code, you will come to know how it looks (yourNamespace.Car / yourNamespace.Tree/ yourNamespace.House)

Comment: 1st line I declare 'var yourNamspace = { Car: function(), Tree: function(), House function()'
2nd line I go straight into '
yourNamespace {
Tree: function() {
const tree_form = document.getElementById('tree_form');
const treeName = document.getElementById('treeName');
const treeHeight = document.getElementById('treeHeight');
.....etc....'
I don't need to put 'var yourNamespace ={};' between the 1st and 2nd line (as above) to redeclare yourNamespace again? -hope that makes more sense

Comment: You do not need to first declare a function and then start writing in it. you can directly start writing your code while you are creating a function in it. if you want to first declare and then you want utilize that function then I can update the answer how you can achieve it.

Comment: Ok I get it. I thought I had to declare the function first. But I can go straight into it. Makes sense, thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yes, the first thing was just a snippet how namespace looks like, and the other snippet is working scenario. Glad to help you

Comment: if it helps don't forget to accept as an answer ;)

Comment: I'm getting a really slow and delayed response on your method above. I tried separating them all and nested each function within a function (so for the example above it was 3 separate functions that had the functions nested within them. This is also causing a very slow and delayed return, is there a faster process?

Comment: Namespace is just to oraganized the messy code, it won't make any delayed in response for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're expecting the JavaScript to magically know which form it's on and which code to run. Sorry. JavaScript is not magic.

Try something like

```
const tree_form = document.getElementById('tree_form');
const car_form = document.getElementById('car_form');

if (tree_form) {
  // all the tree code
}
else if (car_form) {
  // all the car code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the submit button a second time with no value in the other input field then the message has to be shown correct. This is the javascript for the car without your css.

```js
// Car Form
const car_form = document.getElementById('car_form');
const carName  = document.getElementById('carName');
const carColor = document.getElementById('carColor');

car_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    car_Inputs();
});

function car_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const carNameValue  = carName.value.trim();
    const carColorValue = carColor.value.trim();
    
    setErrorForCar(carName, 'Message');
    if (carNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carName, 'Please enter a name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carName);
    }

    setErrorForCar(carColor, 'Message');
    if (carColorValue === '') {
        setErrorForCar(carColor, 'Please enter a color.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForCar(carColor);
    }
}

function setErrorForCar(input, message) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlCar.querySelector('small');
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForCar(input) {
    const formControlCar = input.parentElement;
    formControlCar.className = 'car-form-control success';
}
```

```html
<div class="cars-body">
   <div class="car_container">
     <div class="car_heading_form">
       <h2> Car Form</h2>
     </div>
     <form id="car_form" class="car_form">
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carName">Car Name</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="hank" id="carName" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Message</small>
       </div>
       <div class="car-form-control">
         <label for="carColor">Car Color</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Gold" id="carColor" />
         <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         <small>Message</small>
       </div>
       <button>Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```